# How to use unbase64 function in pyspark SQL query?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I cannot seem to figure out why [unbase64](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unbase64) function won't work in my Spark SQL query.

Here is an example.  I'm trying to decode "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qh" by calling the unbase64 function within the spark SQL.  Any thoughts on why the output doesn't get decoded?  Thanks.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import unbase64

sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

log = [{"eventTime":"2015-12-14 15:27:00","id":"9ab0135f-b8a3-4312-9065-9f8874fd790c","fullLog":"VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qh"}]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(log)

df.registerTempTable('data')

query = sqlContext.sql('SELECT unbase64(fullLog) as test FROM data')

query.write.save("output", format="json")
```

The output is : `{"test":"VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qh"}` when I want it to be: `{"test":"This is a test!"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work for me...

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

log = [("2015-12-14 15:27:00","9ab0135f-b8a3-4312-9065-9f8874fd790c","VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qh")]

rdd_log = sc.parallelize(log)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_log, ["eventTime", "id", "fullLog"])

df.registerTempTable("data")

query = sqlContext.sql('SELECT unbase64(fullLog) as test FROM data')

query = query.select(query.test.cast("string").alias('test'))

print query.collect()

>> [Row(test=u'This is a test!')]
```

Comment: Thanks for testing this out.  Its weird that when I try to output to a file, the decoding doesn't happen, but printing to the screen works.

Comment: Try adding this before the save: query = query.select(query.test.cast("string").alias('test')). It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, the cast to string is an important part